# How do I display a second table on Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle

This is the easiest question ever!

I want to look at two tables side by side. 
But pressing the table I want to display on the connection window, just replaces the exisiting table with the one I just pressed.

Right click -> open, does the same thing.

There's no 'open new window' type option.

How do I do this?

Comment: Might be better answered in the DBA SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drawing pin will pin it to the window. When you open another table, it will open in a new tab. You can right click -> 'New editor tab group' to view them side by side.

Answer (score -1):

Open two instance of SQL Developer. one instance with tableA and other with tableB. Put both window side buy side. this is the easiest way.